# Mimic background-size:cover with amp-img tags

Tags: amp-html

I have images of various sizes (with different width/height ratios as this is user-generated content) and I try to show them in a nice square tile, without stretching them.

In normal HTML, I use `div`s with the image set as `background-image` and a `background-size:cover` property.

Is it possible to achieve this with `amp-img` tags? Not sure which layout I could use to achieve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the same CSS based approach in your AMPs? CSS background images are fully supported by AMP.

Comment: To benefit from the native acceleration / asset selection / rendering optimizations offered by AMP